# Is there a way to have multiple planet systems in Space Engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

I was wondering if there's a way to add multiple planet systems in the game. What I mean by that is having 2-3 Earth-like planets, 2-3 Mars like planets and so on in a single map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way.

Being an administrator (dedicated server) or creative mode (single player), you can access the planet creation menu by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Use spectator mode (<kbd>F8</kbd>) to fly around more quickly. Use the scroll-wheel to adjust spectator mode speed.

If you want to spawn your own asteroids, I recommend creating an empty map for it. Otherwise, use the "Asteroids" scenario for auto-asteroid spawning.

Comment: I recommend to NOT make an empty map for it. An empty map means there also won't be any asteroids spawning.

Comment: You are correct @BadAtPHP. I updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.